# Query Cache vs. MEMORY -stored table

Tags: mysql, caching, query-cache

I plan to optimize the performance of my web application with data caching. It uses MySQL so the options I found so far are these 2:

- use MySQL query cache feature
- make a table using memory storage engine and keep in it the full result of queries as serialized arrays;

I would prefer the second one, since there is only a table I need to cache, and the query cache on table modification invalidates all queries derived from that table at once. 
While in my memory table I can delete only the rows that have been modified (UPDATED). Course this will require more bits of code, but I guess the overall performance would be better.

What do you recommend and why?

Comment: check memcache, mysql query cache will be useless if you have too much updates. mysql memory tables will be hell in management, its hard to be synced, you can use mysql-cluster ndb if you want in memory table with disk sync but multi machine ( or process on same one) is a hassle for most

Comment: Yes, I'll check memcache too, but in the future if I am going to distribute my app to more clients there won't be nice for me to ask them to install memcache on their servers just because my app can't work without it... right?

Comment: oh, I forgot, you can use triggers from mysql directly to update memory table :), or APC instead of memcache, usually its bundled with php

Answer (score -1):

Make a table using memory storage engine and keep in it the full result of queries as serialized arrays;

- 1) You mean session #
  use Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache and message broker
- 2) You mean query cache#

[see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_caching)

hope its help you to make fast web application

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15910058)

Comment: yes bro but it's big thing if see it have lot of detail